# Old manga where two highschool girls are transported to an alien planet where all the aliens are tiny, and the girls have to help with their problems

Tags: story-identification, aliens, manga

Title is pretty much all I remember about the plot, I never actually read it, just saw a couple pages from it. I'm pretty sure it's quite old now, based on the art style.

The only scene i remember seeing was two of the aliens were fighting with each other or something, and the more aggressive/tomboyish(maybe?) of the two sits on him to make him stop.
though my memory may not be 100% on even that, it was a few years ago.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You say "manga" but you say you saw a scene; was it an anime or a manga?

Comment: im fairly certain it was a manga, my memory is of black and white page scans, but... my memory is horrible, i suppose its possible it had an anime, though i think its really rare for an anime to not have a manga first

Comment: Was this a print manga or viewed online? Any idea what year you would have read this? Do you know about where this scene you recall is from, and is this just a one-off or was the whole series about these small aliens?

Comment: I saw it online, I believe it was a scan of a manga page, as i understand, the whole series was about these two girls helping the small aliens with their problems. 
Unfortunately, the only scene I remember is the one described above, which took place in a like, desolate/barren/canyon type area (like where youd expect old dbz fights to take place)